# Notifications on xamarin. Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

Hi I am a polytechnic student. I am totally new to xamarin so I would appreciate any help.

So my problem is I recently followed this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/#run-your-app-in-the-emulator) on how to create notifications on xamarin android and encountered this problem in the `MyBroadcastReceiver.cs`. It says `resource.drawable does not contain a definition for 'SymActionEmail'` under the create notification comment. Any help to fix this would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that the namespace where this class resides ands with `.Android` suffix. This means that the `Android.Resource.Drawable` does not actually reference the Xamarin Android's own `Resource.Drawable` class but your project-specific `Resource.Drawable` class. To overcome you will need to either rename the namespace of this class not to end with `.Android` or add a `using` alias for the default Android namespace:

```
//add this to the using statements in this file
using Sys = Android;
...
//now use the following in your code 
//to use Xamarin Android's built-in Resource.Drawable class
var notification = new Notification( Sys.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail, title );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `global` contextual keyword directly in your code

```
var notification = new Notification(global::Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail, title);
```